# How to concatenate the username in an XML variable?

Tags: xml, ubuntu, ros

I'm defining an argument in my ROS launch file, which is an XML file, and I would like to replace `user` in the definition of the `path` variable with the username variable, that is `$USER`.

```
<arg name = "path" default="/media/user/ssd1/data//" />
```

I've tried combinations of `$USER`, `${USER}`, `@USER` with no luck.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked the [XML roslaunch documentation](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the *env* substitution arg.

```
<arg name="path" default="/media/$(env USER)/ssd1/data/"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @ManceRayder.